# Expo use-font not working after expo publish

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo, yarnpkg, expo-publish

App font is working fine on all platforms before publishing.

Once the app is published, `expo publish`, font is just not showing.

I have added the font through Xcode. [Like that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app).

Font is added to the app following [expo's instructions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/)

Checked, rechecked and reinstalled the yarn package seem to exist (checked by showing some text on screen). Added the package using `yarn add 'use-expo/font'`

This is how the font is loaded:

```
import { useFonts } from "@use-expo/font";

export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Rayando: require("./assets/fonts/crayonsRegular.ttf"),
  });

  return (
    <>
     {fontsLoaded && <Text style={[styles.answerText, {fontFamily: "Rayando"}]}>{number ? 1 : 0}</Text>}
    </>)
}
```

Any advice on how resolve this issue, am I missing something?

Using latest version of expo (37.0.0) expo-cli and yarn.

Comment: are you able to solve this problem? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: Negative. This and another issue made me drop expo

Answer (score 1):

I was also running into a similar problem. As far as I understood `expo publish` does not behave as expected in **ejected** projects: the app loads assets differently.

Found out about this in [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9517#issuecomment-667308918).

The suggested solution is running `expo publish --target managed` or, as of my case, deleting `ios` and `android` folders to convert bare project to expo-managed.